# JavaScript validation for numeric values

Tags: javascript

I want one validation in JavaScript so that a text boxt should allow to enter only numeric values in the following format:

```
4.25
4.50
2.00
```

and so on. There should be always 2 digits after the decimal point and 1 digit before the decimal point. If the user enters 2, it should display as 2.00. This is my requirement.

Answer (score 1):

For having only 2 digits after . you can use [Number()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp).[toFixed](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)(2) function in javscript

`var num = Number(4).toFixed(2)` will give you 4.00

`var num = Number(4.1).toFixed(2)` will give you 4.10

if you do not have number in place after ".", then toFixed will append 0 to your number.

For you second question, probably you can split your number on "." and check the first element is of length 1.